# Downgrading from bootstrap 4 to 3 in yii2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2, composer-php

I was currently working on a project using the yii2 framework. I wanted to try out using bootstrap 4.0 with my project and added `"yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.1.0@dev"` to my `composer.json` file and ran `composer update`.

This successfully installed bootstrap 4.0.0 in the project but when I started to browse my project to see what was affected I realized that the `yii\bootstrap\Modal` component was not working.

Because of this, I want to revert my project back to using bootstrap 3 and changed my entry in the `composer.json` file to `"yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0"` and did a `composer update` but got the following error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap 2.0.8 requires bower-asset/bootstrap 3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap 2.0.7 requires bower-asset/bootstrap 3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/bootstrap 3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap 2.0.5 requires bower-asset/bootstrap 3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap 2.0.4 requires bower-asset/bootstrap 3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap 2.0.3 requires bower-asset/bootstrap 3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap 2.0.2 requires bower-asset/bootstrap 3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap 2.0.1 requires bower-asset/bootstrap 3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.* -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap 2.0.0 requires bower-asset/bootstrap 3.2.* | 3.1.* -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap ~2.0.0 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong or is there another way I can downgrade back to bootstrap 3?

Thanks for any suggestions you might have.

Comment: Try to `composer remove yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap`, and then install it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the `assetManager` to load the specific versions for the jquery and bootstrap files I also did the same in my previous project, I kept everything up to date and just used the following configurations to load the `bootstrap 3` files, you can add the below under `components` in `frontend/config/main.php`.

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
            'sourcePath' => null , 'js' => [ '//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js' ] ,
        ] ,
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
            'sourcePath' => null , 'css' => [ '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' ] ,
        ] ,
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
            'sourcePath' => null , 'js' => [ '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js' ] ,
        ] ,
    ] ,
] ,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `fxpio/composer-asset-plugin`, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin/issues/86#issuecomment-68347825).

You can solve this in 2 ways:

1. Remove `vendor` directory and `composer.lock` file, and then run `composer update`.
2. Switch to [asset-packagist](https://asset-packagist.org/) - you will need to uninstall `fxpio/composer-asset-plugin` and add repository to your composer. More details you can find in [Yii documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets#bower-npm-assets).