# Override Bootstrap CSS/JS of an ActiveForm Yii2

Tags: bootstrap-4, yii2, active-form

In yii2 I have a view which use `yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm` to send data to my model.

After form submission the data is correctly uploaded, but a script named

`<script src="/assets/421ef7ac/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>` is added to my page.

This script somewhat interfers with my current bootstrap, and the page behavior is now broken.

In `main.php` I have set assetManager with this configuration, but this broke the behavior of all my views.

```
   'assetManager' => [
        'linkAssets' => true,

        'bundles' => [
            'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset' => false,

        ]
    ],
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: few things that are not clear. Are you using the `yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm` or `kartik\form\ActiveForm` ?  i think you are using the `kartik\form\ActiveForm` and you need to set the `bsDependencyEnabled` to `false` under the `kartik\form\ActiveFormAsset` array in the `assetManager` component settings , whereas you are setting `yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset` to `false` which is incorrect, another thing is that there is no difference between your **first try** and **second try**   **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: and the link suggests that you should load manually all the assets for the bootstrap version you are using mainly they are the `bootstrap.css` and the `bootstrap.js` files

Comment: You are right, I've refactored my question.
I'm using ````yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm````.

Comment: alright so you are using bootstrap4 and you want to use your own version of the files ? if yes see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883306/downgrading-from-bootstrap-4-to-3-in-yii2/49884457#49884457 for disabling the core script for the jquery and bootstrap loaded by Yii2